# Передать данные из MySQL в Smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Здравствуйте! помогите разобраться:
Есть таблица в БД:

```
        id  f_gdpec w_gdpec     url_gdpec   p_gdspec
        1   Москва  Красноярск  www.test.ru 450
        2   Москва  Красноярск  www.test.ru 900
        3   Москва  Красноярск  www.test.ru 600
```

Необходимо вытащить данные из БД средствами php и вывести средствами smarty.
вот что я сделал:
**module.php**:

```
<?php


function mod_gdspec($module_id){


    $inCore = cmsCore::getInstance(); // подключаем ядро
    $inDB   = cmsDatabase::getInstance(); // подключаем базу
    $cfg    = $inCore->loadModuleConfig($module_id);
    //код модуля
    //Формируем запрос:
    $sql = "SELECT f_gdpec,
                   w_gdpec,
                   url_gdpec,
                   p_gdspec
            FROM cms_gdspec";
    //Выполняем запрос:
    $result = $inDB->query($sql) ;
    /* Считаем количество выведенных записей */         
    if ($inDB->num_rows($result)){
    $items = array();
    //Получаем данные из ответа БД:
        while ($item=$inDB->fetch_assoc($result)){
        $items[]=$item;
        }
    }


    $smarty = $inCore->initSmarty('modules', 'mod_gdspec.tpl');         
    $smarty->assign('items', $items);
    $smarty->display('mod_tags.tpl');

    return true;        
}
?>
```

шаблон:

```
    {foreach item=item from=$items}

<div class="mod_latest_entry">

<div class="mod_latest_f_gdpec">

 {$item.f_gdpec}

</div>

<div class="mod_latest_w_gdpec" >

             {$item.w_gdpec}

  </div>

 </div>
{/foreach}
```

не могу понять в что не так. выводились бы ошибки, может смог бы покопать..
**Модуль не видит шаблона и соответственно данные не передаются в шаблон**
Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Точки с запятой после $items = $item нет..

И, оказывается, я сам опечатался :)

Надо $items[] = $item;

Comment: помогло, только в шаблоне не выводится информация.:(

Comment: как странно, почему то у меня другой шаблон определяется.
и даже если в базе принудительно ставлю нужный шаблон, все равно ничего не показывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP:

```
...
if ($inDB->num_rows($result)){
    $items = array();
    //Получаем данные из ответа БД:
    while ($item=$inDB->fetch_assoc($result)){
        $items[] = $item;
    }
}
...
$smarty->assign('items', $items);
...
```

Smarty:

```
{foreach item=item from=$items}
    <div class="mod_latest_entry">
        <div class="mod_latest_f_gdpec">
             {$item.f_gdpec}
        </div>
        <div class="mod_latest_w_gdpec" 
             {$item.w_gdpec}
        </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Неужели так сложно почитать документацию?  Или просто уже привыкли, что всё за вас делают?

Comment: Буду весьма благодарен ели вы тыкнете меня носом хорошую документацию.

Comment: Вот вы использовали третью скобку в вашем примере PHP, правильно понимаю, что здесь заканчивается : function mod_module_main($module_id)?
И не нужна проверка на true и false?

Comment: Не, третья скобка - это я промахнулся :)

Документация по Смарти: http://smarty.net/manual/ru/

Comment: В описание вопроса, написал как сделал, и все равно не работет. Причем если данный блок подключаю, то у меня не грузится остальная страница.

Answer (score 0):

вот рабочий вариант, допилил:)
    <?php

```
function mod_gdspec($module_id){

        $inCore = cmsCore::getInstance(); // подключаем ядро
        $inDB   = cmsDatabase::getInstance(); // подключаем базу
        $cfg    = $inCore->loadModuleConfig($module_id);
        //код модуля
        //Формируем запрос:
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cms_gdspec";
        //Выполняем запрос:
        $result = $inDB->query($sql) ;
        /* Считаем количество выведенных записей */         
        if ($inDB->num_rows($result)){
        $items = array();   
        //Получаем данные из ответа БД:
            while ($gdt = $inDB->fetch_assoc($result)){
            $items[] = $gdt;
            }
        }

        $smarty = $inCore->initSmarty('modules', 'mod_gdspec.tpl');         
        $smarty->assign('items', $items);
        $smarty->display('mod_gdspec.tpl');

        return true;        
}
?>
```

шаблон:
    {foreach key=id item=gdt from=$items}
        <div class="mod_latest_entry">
            <div class="mod_latest_f_gdpec">
                 {$gdt.f_gdpec}
            </div>
            <div class="mod_latest_w_gdpec"> 
                 {$gdt.w_gdpec}
            </div>
        </div>
    {/foreach}

немного отличается от предложенного:) но суть таже:)